# Looking for a Python shorthand way of parsing a url encoded string into tuples

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples

I have a string `rssi=199&phase=-1&doppler=-1` and I am trying to parse it to look like `[('rssi', '199'), ('phase', '-1'), ('doppler', '-1')]` using Python.

Currently, I have a working function that does what I want. It goes like this:

```py
s = 'rssi=199&phase=-1doppler=-1'
spl = s.split('&') # now looks like ['rssi=199', 'phase=-1', 'doppler=-1']
l = []
for i in spl:
    l.append(tuple(i.split('=')))
print l # finally have [('rssi', '199'), ('phase', '-1'), ('doppler', '-1')]
```

I'm looking for a shorter way to accomplish this task in fewer lines. Just to understand how I can clean up the code and for best-practice. I've seen operations in python that look like `[ x.strip() for x in foo.split(";") if x.strip() ]` with the for loop inside the array. I don't totally understand what that does and don't know what it is called. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: That notation is called *list comprehension*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure you are asking about is called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).  You could replace your `for` loop with:

```
[v.split('=') for v in s.split('&')]
```

Which would give you a list like:

```
[['rssi', '199'], ['phase', '-1'], ['doppler', '-1']]
```

But for what you're doing, the `urlparse.parse_qs` method might be easier:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> urlparse.parse_qs('rssi=199&phase=-1&doppler=-1')
{'phase': ['-1'], 'rssi': ['199'], 'doppler': ['-1']}
```

...or `urlparse.parse_qsl`, if you really want a list/tuple instead of a dict:

```
>>> urlparse.parse_qsl('rssi=199&phase=-1&doppler=-1')
[('rssi', '199'), ('phase', '-1'), ('doppler', '-1')]
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me list comprehension. Also thank you even more for the urlparse lib. I didn't notice the query string part and used it wrong before.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`urlparse.parse_qsl`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qsl):

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> urlparse.parse_qsl("foo=bar&bar=baz")
[('foo', 'bar'), ('bar', 'baz')]
```

It may also be helpful to turn this into a dictionary:

```
>>> dict(urlparse.parse_qsl("foo=bar&bar=baz"))
{'foo': 'bar', 'bar': 'baz'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you started with a URL, split on `?` and removed the host and path, and now are trying to parse the query string. You might want to use `urlparse` from the beginning.

```
import urlparse

parsed = urlparse.urlparse('http://www.bob.com/index?rssi=199&phase=-1&doppler=-1')
print parsed.hostname + parsed.path 
# www.bob.com/index

query_tuples = urlparse.parse_qsl(parsed.query)
print query_tuples 
# [('rssi', '199'), ('phase', '-1'), ('doppler', '-1')]
```